# Routes not working after Laravel 5.3 upgrade

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm trying upgrade my laravel project from 5.2 to 5.3.

Since laravel 5.3, the route files are kept in a separate directory `routes`, instead of the previous `app\Http` directory.  I created the file routes/web.app and pasted my routes into this file.

When i execute `php artisan route:list`, it returns:

```
+--------+----------+-------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI               | Name | Action                                     | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | captcha/{config?} |      | \Mews\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptcha | web        |
+--------+----------+-------------------+------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
```

My `routes/web.php` file:

```
<?php 
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */
    Route::get('/', function(){
        echo 'here';
    });
```

Where is my route?

When I access the home page, it returns a 404 error, but the error comes from laravel.

The file `.htaccess` is ok.

Comment: simply go and dowload the files in laravel 5.3 version and start your project in there.There are some differences in  folder structure in the new version.Better to not to edit the files in 5.2 version according to the files in 5.3 version.

Comment: @Kalanka the OP said he's upgrading his project, not starting a new one. running `composer update` doesn't create the new folder structure. strange that this breaking change is not documented in the upgrade guide.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I created the file routes/web.app and past my routes on file.

In Laravel 5.3 the web.php file is already created in the routes directory. If you have recreated this file that is where the problem may be propagating from.

Comment: When I ran the composer update the file routes/web.php do not was created

I copied the content of app/Http/routes.php and created the file   routes/web.php and paste the content.

Answer (score 0):

I read the upgrade documentation and thought I needed to remove the EventServiceProvider, RouteServiceProvider, AuthServiceProvider methods from the boot ....

But in fact I needed to update the contents of these files.
After updating the contents to the new version 5.3 up to where I tested, it is working ....